# Tiling a W * 2H-1 floor with infinitely available H * 1 and 1 * H tiles

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am having a hard time solving this question I came across:

You are given a tile of dimension `H * 1` and a floor of dimension `W * (2H-1)`. You need to find out all **possible ways** of tiling the floor with the given tile. The width W is guaranteed to be a multiple of H, so this is always possible.

**Inputs:** W, H
**Output:** No. of ways to tile the floor.

I am trying dynamic programming and having difficulty in figuring out the sub-problems and writing the recurrence. Below is my approach:

Consider the corner of the floor. A tile can be laid out there either horizontally or vertically. Using this dichotomy, the recurrence is:

If `H` is **even**:

```
f[W][0] = f[w-H][0] + 2.{ f[W-H][1]+f[W-H][2]+...+f[W-H][H/2] }
```

If `H` is **odd**:

```
f[W][0] = f[W-H][0] + 2.{ f[W-H][1]+f[W-H][2]+...+f[W-H][floor(H/2)] } + f[W-H][ceil(H/2)]
```

where

```
f[W][0] = No. of ways of tiling floor of dimension (W*(2H-1)) with H*1 tiles.
```

and

```
f[W][i] = No. of ways of tiling floor of dimension (W*(2H-1)) with 1 extra tile at 'i'th position in horizontal position at bottommost row.
```

Below is a diagram for f[W][1]

```
-1 2 3 4 5 ... (2H-1)

1 _ _ _ _ _ ... _

2 _ _ _ _ _ ... _

3 _ _ _ _ _ ... _

.

.

.

W _ _ _ _ _ ... _

           _(This tile is laid out horizontally here)
```

How do I further break down the sub-problems `f[W-H][i] for 0 < i <= H/2`? Any suggestion/solution would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide link to problem for better understanding.

Comment: i can only make of some observations...
As the height is 2H-1, you can at most put 1 vertical tile at a column?
Then either (2H-1) horizontal tiles can be put or  1 vertical + (H-1)horizontal tiles can be put...for first case, sub problem is easily go to (W-H, 2*H-1),  for second case I have no idea yet...